# Tablet to laptop bluetooth storage

Tags: bluetooth

I was wondering if there was a way to connect my tablet to my laptop by bluetooth and access the contents as if it was wired in.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not without both devices supporting any functionality like that. It may be possible that your tablet / laptop as if it were a native drive, but the device would have to support it, and it would have to support the drivers on both devices, so it seems unlikely.

Bluetooth *does* support the Object Exchange (OBEX) protocol, but not all bluetooth stacks or devices support it, though it is a common enough feature of Bluetooth. If both devices support OBEX, then you can make one-off transfers of files from device-to-device. Generally it would by you pairing your bluetooth devices, then selecting a group of files you want to send to a paired device.